# Join multiple tables with one JPQL query

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I got this sql-query I want to create as query in JPQL but I cannot get it right. I got a manytoone relationship between QuestionAnswers and QuizQuestions:

SQL:

```
SELECT quizName, question, answer FROM Quiz 
JOIN QuizQuestions on Quiz.quizId = QuizQuestions.Quiz_QuizId 
JOIN QuestionAnswers on QuizQuestions.questionId = QuestionAnswers.question_questionId 
WHERE quiz.quizId = 1;
```

JPQL query:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT q.quizName, f.question, a.answer FROM Quiz q, QuizQuestions f, QuestionAnswers a LEFT JOIN QuestionAnswers ON f.questionId=a.question.questionId");
```

I get syntax error in Intellij.

What can be wrong?

Im using EclipseLink

**EDIT**
solved it like this with just one join:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT f.quiz.quizName FROM QuizQuestions f JOIN QuestionAnswers qa WHERE f.questionId = qa.question.questionId");
```

Comment: Well, that's just not how joins work in JPQL. Read some documentation on JPQL. Just googling for "JPQL joins" leads to [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#JOIN) for example, or [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join), which explain how joins work.

Comment: Thanks. I saw those links as well. But still having problems of getting it right
Any hint of how to edit my query? Thanks

Comment: Hi! Show us the code of the entities QuizQuestions and QuestionAnswers

Answer (score 6):

Probably, you are looking for a JPQL like this:

```
SELECT quiz.name, quizquestion.question, questionasnswer.answer FROM Quiz quiz
JOIN quiz.quizQuestions quizquestion
JOIN quizquestion.questionAnswers questionasnswer
WHERE quiz.id = 1;
```

I would evict solutions with `qa.question.questionId` (tableA.tableB.column), because the JPA framework not always generate nice SQLs from this. Always explicit the JOINs in the JPQL.